# Скрипт прокрутки страницы не работает в ие

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, explorer

На странице горизонтальное меню, которое имеет `position: fixed`, при переходе по ссылка этого меню страница плавно прокручивается вниз до нужной информации вот таким скриптом

```
    $(function () {
    var topMenu = $('.nav'),
        menuItems = topMenu.find('a'),

        scrollItems = menuItems.map(function () {
            var item = $($(this).attr('href'));
            if (item.length) {
                return item;
            }
        }),

        hash = window.location.hash;

    menuItems.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - 20;
        window.history.replaceState('', '', href);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

скрипт совершенно не работает в ие - ни в 9, ни в 8, ни в 7.
Каким образом можно заставить его работать в ие?
Вот код http://jsfiddle.net/UB9f9/10/

Comment: Почитайте эту статью, наверное там есть ответ
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333911/jquery-animate-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет я бы сделал так:

```
$('nav a').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var elid = $(this).attr('href');
    var toscr = $(elid).offset().top + 'px';
    $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop':toscr}, 400);

});
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/wjunB/

P.S у IE9 что какая то проблема с jQuery 1.10.1?? Почему это чудо НЕ работает в IE: http://jsfiddle.net/LWjmY/

Comment: ага, спасибо, работает. а как в твой скрипт еще добавить смещение позиции на 20 пикселов вот сюда `var toscr = $(elid).offset().top + 'px'; `?

Comment: так вроде в jQuery 1.10.1 отказались от поддержки ие9 и более ранних версий, не?

Comment: а, всё, понятно, `var toscr = $(elid).offset().top + 20 - 'px';`